# Spotlight not showing applications owned by root

Tags: spotlight

Somehow my spotlight is not working correct.

After each reboot it will show only dictionary items. Then when I do
    sudo mdutil -E / 
it will find many items.
However applications shown are only which are owned by myself, applications owned by root will not show.

So basically I have two questions,

Why is spotlight not working properly at startup and must be reindexed always.

Should I take ownerships of all applications to myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your volume permissions are incorrect.  You don't say what version of OS X you're running, but the usual fix is to open Disk Utility, select the volume and Repair Permissions on it.

After that, reboot so that processes launch under the correct permissions and it should be working as expected.

Comment: This did not work. I am at Yosemite 10.10.4, in terminal 'diskutil verifyvolume /' will give Error -69845 (Filesystem verify or repair failed) underlying error: 8 : POSIX reports : Exec format error. If in terminal 'sudo diskutil repairvolume /' error : Error starting filerepair for disk0s2 xx Unable to unmount volume for repair

Comment: Well to continue, after above and reboot total disaster, my mac will not boot anymore :) :) Am now busy copying files in single user mode and will do a fresh reinstall